# SQLServerAgent could not be started

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Do you know why I have got this error and how fix it.

> SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: This installation of SQL
>   Server Agent is disabled.  The edition of SQL Server that installed
>   this service does not support SQL Server Agent.).

My server parameters:

```
10.0.5500.0 SP3 Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit)
```

Comment: What part of "The edition of SQL Server that installed this service does not support SQL Server Agent" are you failing to comprehend?

Comment: Do you know what I have to do to create jobs or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Agent is not available with Express editions : (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx). That's why, for example, you can't schedule report production on Reporting Services.

You may want to batch [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

===== EDIT =====

simple sample:

```
save.sql -----
backup database dbname to disk = 'somepath' with init, format
save.bat -----
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE"  -S instanceName -E -i save.sql -o save.log
```

you may now schedule save.bat (with the windows task scheduler) to make a full backup of dbname

Comment: Do you have some good example to this?

Comment: It really depends on what you plan to schedule.

Comment: I need every 5 minute exec procedure and this is problem for me. Maybe you have got idea how to do it in another way?

Comment: really easy indeed, just schedule `sqlcmd -S instance -Q "exec dbName.dbo.procName" -E` to run every 5 minutes in windows scheduler

Comment: sqlcmd -S instance -Q "exec Raf.dbo.OsobaProcedura" -E
HResult 0x35, Level 16, State 1
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in
stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

Comment: well... you must replace `instance` by the name of you sql instance and if you have space in your object name, use bracket `"exec [Raf].[dbo].[OsobaPro cedura]"`. If you have a default instance, the -S is optional.

Comment: sqlcmd was created but doesn`t work every 5 minutes do you know why?

Comment: wait I have to check again... :)

Comment: doesn`t work every 5 minutes :(

Comment: only when I exec this in cmd

Comment: ok work :) "windows scheduler "